# Android GPS as an Activity

Tags: android

This is working perfectly for me.

```
public class GPSActivity extends Activity {
LocationManager locmgr = null;
String android_id;
DbAdapter db;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    db = new DbAdapter(getBaseContext());
    db.open();

    android_id = Secure.getString(getBaseContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    locmgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locmgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 5, this.onLocationChange);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Waiting for location..." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

  LocationListener onLocationChange=new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            String latlong = "Lat: " + loc.getLatitude() + " Long: " + loc.getLongitude();  
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), latlong, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try{ 
                 db.insertGPSCoordinates(android_id, Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()), Double.toString(loc.getLongitude()));
            }
            catch(Exception e){
            }
        } 
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
        Bundle extras) {
        }
    };

    //pauses listener while app is inactive
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locmgr.removeUpdates(onLocationChange);
    }

    //reactivates listener when app is resumed
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        locmgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 5, onLocationChange);
    }
  }
```

How do I use this from Broadcastreceiver ? I want to to start collecting co-ordinates when BOOT_COMPLETE.  And keep that running depending on that    `locmgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 5, this.onLocationChange);`  setting. I am getting confused how to keep that working periodically.

Comment: Do I need LocationListener in service ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use and activity for this stuff. Use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). Here's what you do. Have a broadcast receiver that receives the BOOT_COMPLETE broadcast. When it receives the broadcast have it start up a service. In this service is where you put all your code for recording the locations. The service won't stop until you call stopService on it of for what ever reason you have your service call stopSelf().